# Create Java object from external java file

Tags: java, object

How can I load a *.java  class file into my java app and create an object based on that class file?

Comment: The language is a bit confusing. It's either a source file (ending with .java) or it's a class file (ending on .class). A class file is created by the compiler when compiling a .java file. Which do you have?

Answer (score 7):

You can do it by using classes inside `javax.tools`. You will have a `ToolProvider` class from which you can obtain a compiler instance and compile code at runtime. Later you will load `.class` files just compiled separately with a `ClassLoader` unless you obtain directly a binary code for the class and you are able to istantiate it directly.

Take a look [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try Janino's [SimpleCompiler](http://dist.codehaus.org/janino/javadoc/org/codehaus/janino/SimpleCompiler.html).  Simple example, assuming you're compiling a class with a public no-arg constructor.

```
import org.codehaus.janino.SimpleCompiler;

public class JaninoSimpleTest
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable
  {
    String filename = args[0];
    String className = args[1];
    SimpleCompiler compiler = new SimpleCompiler(filename);
    ClassLoader loader = compiler.getClassLoader();
    Class compClass = loader.loadClass(className);
    Object instance = compClass.newInstance();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i Think this will help : [Package Summary](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/package-summary.html)
Or [Simple Comipler](http://dist.codehaus.org/janino/javadoc/org/codehaus/janino/SimpleCompiler.html) .

Answer (score -1):

You cannot. The .java file needs to be compiled into a .class so that you can use it.

Comment: Isn't there a java library to compile java code into classes?

Comment: @Jack that doesn't make his answer not true.  All @ivans is saying is that the .java file has to be compiled first and that he can't magically get a class loaded from a .java file without compiling somehow.

Comment: That's true, you should point it out in a comment that what he is asking it's not clear, not as an answer :) I won't -1 anyway..